# On the SQL tab what is happening during the Offset time?

Tags: glimpse

On the SQL tab in Glimpse, there is the Duration column next to the Records column which I suppose is the execution time of the command, and then the next column is a time period labeled Offset. What is that actually measuring? Then there is the Duration at the far right of the column that I was guessing is the total time, but the two detailed columns to add up to that total.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first duration column is the duration, in milliseconds, for the command. (Your query).

The offset column is the length of time, in milliseconds, since the beginning of the request.

The second duration column is the duration, in milliseconds, of the open connection time to the database. Often one command will run on one connection, but sometimes you'll see multiple commands happening within the same connection.